# Completeness of push up and biceps curls for upper arm

Tags: push-ups, biceps, triceps

I know that for a complete exercise, you need to concentrate on many muscle groups. For example, extreme abs training with no back exercises can cause serious posture problem in the long run.

My question is, is it enough to do biceps curls for biceps and push-ups for triceps to completely work the upper arms out? Or should I include extra triceps exercises like triceps extensions?

If it helps, I am 171cm/69kg. I use 6 kg dumbbells for 24x3 curls. I only use my body weight for 10x3 push-ups. My long term goal is to become lean and fit. I am not interested in putting large amounts of muscle mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Elbow extension = 1 Elbow flexion

The exercises must also be selected intelligently, if you do normal standing bicep curls then tricep pushdowns are ok.

but if you do for example preacher curls where the long head of the tricep is semi-flexed from the beginning then you need to do tricep kickbacks.

Or if you do drag curls where the long head of the bicep is extended then you need to do overhead tricep extensions.

Push ups also use the biceps so you are pretty much working your biceps way more than your triceps.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not bodybuilding but "Physical Fitness" SE; I would like to give my 2cents.

You actually do not need to work your arms directly. During your pull and push exercises (pull-up, row, push-up, overhead push) those two muscles work as needed. The isolation exercises you do "are not mandatory" for general fitness, maybe for extra muscle building.